# PHP Nested Array is misaligned

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP loop that is pushing data into an array that will eventually be used to create a list of `select` options in my dropdown.

I feel like it is kinda close but I am doing something wrong somewhere.

The array of `types` needs to be part of the `category` it is associated with.

```
// Get the list of behavior types
public function _behavior_types()
{

    $cat = $this->global_model->get_behavior_categories();
    $typ = $this->global_model->get_behavior_types();
    $output = array();

    // Loop over our categories
    foreach($cat as $c)
    {
        // Push the category name to an array
        $output[] = $c['categoryName'];

        // Loop over our types
        foreach($typ as $t)
        {   
            // If this type belongs to the category we are currently in, add it to the array
            if($t['categoryID'] == $c['categoryID'])
            {
                array_push($output, $t);
            }
        }

    }

    return $output;
}
```

I have something out of place however and its causing the array to not be set up in the correct way.

Here is the current output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Negative
    [1] => Array
        (
            [categoryID] => 2
            [points] => -3
            [typeID] => 4
            [typeName] => Bad School Day
        )

    [2] => Positive
    [3] => Array
        (
            [categoryID] => 1
            [points] => 2
            [typeID] => 1
            [typeName] => Ate Dinner
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [categoryID] => 1
            [points] => 2
            [typeID] => 3
            [typeName] => Brushed Teeth
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [categoryID] => 1
            [points] => 3
            [typeID] => 2
            [typeName] => Completed Homework
        )

)
```

Here is my desired output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Negative
        [0] => Array
            (
                [categoryID] => 2
                [points] => -3
                [typeID] => 4
                [typeName] => Bad School Day
            )

    [1] => Positive
        [0] => Array
            (
                [categoryID] => 1
                [points] => 2
                [typeID] => 1
                [typeName] => Ate Dinner
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [categoryID] => 1
                [points] => 2
                [typeID] => 3
                [typeName] => Brushed Teeth
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [categoryID] => 1
                [points] => 3
                [typeID] => 2
                [typeName] => Completed Homework
            )

)
```

The dropdown in turn will look like:

```
Negative
  Bad day at school
Positive
  Ate Dinner
  Brushed Teeth
  Completed Homework
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your desired output is not really a valid array structure, at least how you have it typed. `$output[0]` cannot be both a string `Negative` and an array of options.  I suggest making the category the key something like this:

```
// Get the list of behavior types
public function _behavior_types()
{

    $cat = $this->global_model->get_behavior_categories();
    $typ = $this->global_model->get_behavior_types();
    $output = array();

    // Loop over our categories
    foreach($cat as $c)
    {
        // Push the category name to an array
        $output[$c['categoryName']] = array();

        // Loop over our types
        foreach($typ as $t)
        {   
            // If this type belongs to the category we are currently in, add it to the array
            if($t['categoryID'] == $c['categoryID'])
            {
                array_push($output[$c['categoryName']], $t);
            }
        }

    }

    return $output;
}
```